# How can i set a background image like that?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Have a look at this website: http://www.omnomburger.at/. As you can, see when scroling down it looks like the background image is fixed. And one of those pages is like a window, through which you can see the background image. How can i create this effect?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you might wanna do

```
body {
        background-image: url(path to img);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
```